# DDMathParser - Adding a constant

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

How can one add there own constants into the DDMathParser? Like for example Fe = 55.845.

And I would be able to use this like pi().

THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the DDMathParser wiki, built-in constants like pi [are functions that take no arguments](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Built-in-Functions).

The wiki also describes how to [define your own functions](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Adding-New-Functions).

Comment: +1 this is exactly right. If you also want to use a special symbol for the constant (such as `π` for `pi()`), then you'll have to add that symbol to the [single character function set](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/blob/master/DDMathParser/DDMathStringTokenizer.m#L76).  By default, function names can only be alphanumeric.